# clear mocks between tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I fail to understand how jest works.

consider the following setup.
I have a "dependency" module like so :

**dependency.js**

```
function doSomething(y) {
    console.log(y);
}

export {doSomething}
```

I have a module that uses this dependency :

**MyModule.js**

```
import { doSomething } from './dependency';

let alreadyDid;

export default (x) => {
    if (alreadyDid)
        throw "error";

    doSomething(x * 2);
    alreadyDid = true;
}
```

my test file look like the following  (I'm using require & jest.resetModules in order to reset the module "state")

**MyModule.test.js**

```
jest.mock('./dependency', () => ({doSomething: jest.fn()}))
import { doSomething } from './dependency';

let myModuleDo;

describe('myModule', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        myModuleDo = require('./MyModule').default;
        jest.resetModules();
    });

    it('calls the dependency with double the input', () => {
        myModuleDo(2);

        expect(doSomething).toBeCalledWith(4);
    });

    it('calls the dependency with double the input', () => {
        myModuleDo(1);

        expect(doSomething).toBeCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

The problem is that the second test always failed, with the actual count as 4, as if it remembers the first call.
when I switch between the 2, I get the opposite (2 instead of 4).

I tried using mockReset() in afterEach, but then the second test fail on "not called".

any idea what's happen here ?

**UPDATE**
I realized I need to replace the "import" with require in order to get a new mock in each test.

so now I'm confused - most of the jest examples are with "import" rather than "require". I almost don't see examples, or patterns explaining we need to use require in order to properly use the jest.fn().

What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick fix is to reset the `doSomething.mock.calls = [];` in `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `doSomething.mockClear()` in the before each. Also you shouldn't have to do this: `myModuleDo = require('./MyModule').default;` in the before each nor use `jest.resetModules();`. Also, if you want the mock `doSomething` to return a specific value for each test, you can set up the `jest.fn()` to return a value `e.g. jest.fn(() => 'some value here')`